# Creating a Yii 1.1 Blog App with like dislike option for posts

Tags: yii, blogs

Need full code guidance for creating a like dislike option for post in Yii 1.1 Blog Application, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Probably add a field, or two, to the post table. Add new action, or two, to the controller. Then add your links for up/down voting to the _view.php file, set to the new action(s). In the actions increment/decrement the new field(s).

Comment: would I be needing a separate table to store info of post_id and user_id also would ill be needing a like controller or model is enough I don't know much about this framework it is my project to make a simple blog with post comment and like I have made till comment with the help of documentation I need help with the like dislike.

Comment: You can add in post table itself. But if you want to do it in separate table then also you can do it

Comment: would it be possible for us to connect via screen share I really want a full guidance I am lost. 9833758969 this is my watsapp